# ordered pair of unequal positive integer solution of $x+y+z+w = 20$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

[1] Number of ordered pair of unequal positive integer solution of $x+y+z = 10$

[2] Number of ordered pair of unequal positive integer solution of $x+y+z+w = 20$

$\bf{My\; Try}::$ For $(1)$ one:: Here $x,y,z>0$ and $x,y,z\in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$

$\bullet $ If $x=1$, Then $y+z=9$, So $(y,z) = (2,7)\;,(3,6)\;,(4,5)\;(5,4)\;,(6,3)\;,(7,2)$

$\bullet $ If $x=2$ Then $y+z=8$, So $(y,z) = (1,7)\;,(3,5)\;,(5,3)\;(7,1)$

$\bullet $ If $x=3$ Then $y+z=7$, So $(y,z) = (1,6)\;,(2,5)\;,(5,2)\;(6,1)$

$\bullet $ If $x=4$ Then $y+z=6$, So $(y,z) = (1,5)\;,(5,1)$.

$\bullet $ If $x=5$ Then $y+z=5$, So $(y,z) = (1,4)\;,(2,3)\;,(3,2)\;(4,1)$

$\bullet $ If $x=6$ Then $y+z=4$, So $(y,z) = (1,3)\;,(3,1)$

$\bullet $ If $x=7$ Then $y+z=3$, So $(y,z) = (1,2)\;,(2,1)$

So Total unordered pair is $ = 24$

My Question is , is there is any other Method to calculate the ordered pair in less complex way

because above is very Lengthy method

Help Required

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, let's look at this for a general sum, $S$.  We seek triples of unequal positive integers $(x,y,z)$ with $x+y+z=S$.  We can count them by assuming $x<y<z$, and multiply the resulting count by $3!=6$.

Since we are assuming $x<y<z$, we must have 
$$
x+(x+1)+(x+2) \le S
$$
so $3x+3 \le S$, i.e., $x\le (S/3)-1$.

As well, $y+(y+1)\le S-x$, i.e., $2y+1 \le S-x$, i.e. $y \le (S-x-1)/2.$

Once $x$ and $y$ are chosen, this forces the value of $z$, and so the quantity you seek is $6$ times
$$
f(S)=\sum_{x:1 \le x \le \frac{S}{3}-1} \sum_{y:x+1\le y \le \frac{S-x-1}{2}} 1
= \sum_{x:1 \le x \le \frac{S}{3}-1} \left( \left\lfloor \frac{S-x-1}{2}\right\rfloor -x\right)
$$
Calculating this for various $S$, starting with $S=6$, we have the sequence
$$1,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,10,12,14,16,19,21,24,27,30,33,37,40,44,... .$$
For your $S=10$, we get the value $4$, which when multiplied by $6$ yields your 24.

This sequence appears to be (a shift of) http://oeis.org/A001399, and from the entry there, it seems that $$f(S)=\mathrm{round}\left( \frac{(S-3)^2}{12} \right)$$
and I've verified that for $6\le S\le 10000$, so it's pretty surely correct.  A proof is probably among the many references at that OEIS entry.

Answer (score 3):

We use that the number of positive integer solutions of $2X+Y=N$ (where $N$ is a positive integer) is $\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2}\rfloor$.

(This is because solving $N-2X=Y\ge 1$ gives $X\le\frac{N-1}{2}$.)

---

[1]

Let us first consider the case $x\lt y\lt z$.

Letting $y=x+a,z=y+b$ where $a,b$ are positive integers, we see that $$x+y+z=10$$ is equivalent to
$$3x+2a+b=10$$

We have $10-3x=2a+b\ge 3$, so $x=1,2$.

- For $x=1$, the number of solutions is $\lfloor\frac{7-1}{2}\rfloor=3$.
- For $x=2$, the number of solutions is $\lfloor\frac{4-1}{2}\rfloor=1$.

Therefore, the answer is $(3+1)\times 3!=\color{red}{24}$.

---

[2]

Let us first consider the case $x\lt y\lt z\lt w$.

Letting $y=x+a,z=y+b,w=z+c$ where $a,b,c$ are positive integers, we see that $$x+y+z+w=20$$ is equivalent to
$$4x+3a+2b+c=20$$
We have $20-4x=3a+2b+c\ge 6$, so $x=1,2,3$.

- For $x=1$, we have $16-3a=2b+c\ge 3$, so $a=1,2,3,4$. So, the number of solutions is $\lfloor\frac{13-1}{2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{10-1}{2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{7-1}{2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{4-1}{2}\rfloor=14$.
- For $x=2$, we have $12-3a=2b+c\ge 3$, so $a=1,2,3$. So, the number of solutions is
  $\lfloor\frac{9-1}{2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{6-1}{2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{3-1}{2}\rfloor=7$.
- For $x=3$, we have $8-3a=2b+c\ge 3$, so $a=1$. So, the number of solutions is $\lfloor\frac{5-1}{2}\rfloor=2$.

Therefore, the answer is $(14+7+2)\times 4!=\color{red}{552}$.

Comment: Is there any particular name given to this technique?

Comment: @Sahaj Satish Sharma : Well, I don't know.